DacPac omitting FORMAT_OPTIONS for External File Format
I have an external file format defined in my sql project.
The sql target platform is Azure Synapse Analytics Serverless SQL Pool.
The file format looks like this:
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [SynapseDelimitedTextFormat]
WITH (
FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
FORMAT_OPTIONS (FIELD_TERMINATOR = N';', FIRST_ROW = 2, USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = False)
);

But after building and deploying a DacPac of the project via SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1, the resulting file format in the database ends up like this
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [SynapseDelimitedTextFormat]
WITH (
FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
FORMAT_OPTIONS (FIELD_TERMINATOR = N';')
);

Notice the missing options.
The issue can also be observed by doing a schema compare, in visual studio, against a database which has the proper file format with alle the options. the FIRST_ROW and USE_TYPE_DEFAULT options will be missing when viewing the file format in the compare window.
I've reported this to microsoft, as i suspect its a bug on their end, but this issue is rather pressing, so i wanted to see if anyone on here has a solution or workaround.

What is the result if you build and deploy using Visual Studio from your local develop machine? Are the options also missed?

I've unziped and compared the models from the dacpac built locally and the one created during the CICD flow. They are identical. The file format looks like this in both:





I'm not really willing to do any deployments before having a possible fix, as it's a pain cleaning up an incorrect file format in the db.

Based on your comment, the issue looks like is occurring when deploying the Dacpac file rather than building. @FS'Wæhre

I understand your reasoning, however the issue also happens in revers, if you import an existing db, with the correct file format, into a sql project in visual studio, the file format will be missing the first row option in this case as well.

Based on my research, in Azure Synapse Analytics "USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = False" is the default setting and also is the only supported setting when "FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEX". It seems that "FIRST_ROW = 2" also is the default setting. I think that the system might automatically omit the default settings when import/export the SQL scripts. @FS'Wæhre

That would explain it, but when FIRST_ROW = 2 was omittes in our case the behaviour was as if FIRST_ROW was set to 1.. Maybe the default behaviour is something which can be changed on the database? I'll need to look into it. @BrightRan-MSFT thanks for all the replies

You're welcome. And please go ahead to check the database. @FS'Wæhre

As we have discussed above, consider to check whether the following format options of external file format might be omitted when import/publish or export the SQL scripts from Azure Synapse Analytics Serverless SQL pools:

The specified value of the option is the default one.

The option is not supported for the specified FORMAT_TYPE.

The option is not supported for Serverless SQL pools.






i've checked and the default behaviour is FIRST_ROW = 1, this default behaviour is not possible to configure/change.
2./3. - Eveything works as intended if i add the file format directly in the database, only when deploying a dacpac does the issue occure.



I guess ill have to wait and hear what MS has to say.

@FS'Wæhre, All right. Please go ahead.
